# Migration from kubernetes-cluster to docker-compose files

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, containerd

I am currently trying to "migrate" from a running Kubernetes cluster (the pods are running on containerd) to docker-compose files.
My goal is to have all the information in the docker-compose file. This information should be stored by each pod in the cluster as a docker-compose file.
Currently I am trying "COMPOSE TO KUBERNETES". Unfortunately, it seems to me that it is the wrong way around.

I tried the following

```
sudo kubectl get deployments,services,pods --namespace <NAMESPACE> -o yaml > k8s-resources.yaml
```

After that

```
kompose convert --volumes hostPath -f k8s-resources.yaml

ERRO Could not parse config for project docker : yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 1: cannot unmarshal !!str `v1` into config.RawService
  line 3: cannot unmarshal !!seq into config.RawService
  line 4400: cannot unmarshal !!str `List` into config.RawService 
FATA composeObject.Parse() failed, Failed to load compose file: yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 1: cannot unmarshal !!str `v1` into config.RawService
  line 3: cannot unmarshal !!seq into config.RawService
  line 4400: cannot unmarshal !!str `List` into config.RawService
```

Comment: Kompose runs in the opposite direction – it starts _from_ a `docker-compose.yml` file and converts _to_ Kubernetes YAML.  It also requires enough adjusting the results that you more or less have to learn the Kubernetes syntax anyways.  Compose's model is much simpler than Kubernetes's, and I wonder if you could read through the Deployment YAML files in source control and hand-write the Compose file.

Answer (score 0):

The unmarshal error message suggests that there is a conversion issue with the syntax of the YAML file you are trying to convert.  Follow below steps to get rid of this errors :

- As per the [docker official doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/), if you are using the
  docker-compose.yaml version v1, Can you change the version from V1 to
  V2 or V3 in docker-compose.yml as v1 is going to be deprecated and
  this will reduce the errors.
- If you want to see what your YAML input looks like as JSON or Python
  use [yaml-online-parser.appspot.com](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) created by Paul Tarjan and
  convert accordingly as there might be some conversion issues with
  strings. You can also refer to the [unmarshal interface doc](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3#Unmarshaler) by Go
  yaml community which guides you in correct conversion.
- In addition,you can also make use of the [Kubernetes to docker
  compose conversion tool](https://8gwifi.org/kube2.jsp).